# Background thread freezes WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, multithreading, webview

I inject `JavaScript` interface to my `WebView`, and once I get to my native methods that I defined in the `JavaScript`, if freezes the `WebView`until I return a value.
For example:

In this example the `WebView` is stuck for the **8 seconds**. I also double-checked that it is not the main thread, and it is indeed NOT the main thread, so I just don't see a reason why would it freeze the `WebView`.

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface( new WebViewHandler.JavaScriptInterface(), "webCallHandler" );

public class JavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String jsToAndroidNativeFunc(String Data)
    {

        Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    if( Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper() )
                        Log.d("TAG","Main Thread");
                    else
                        Log.d("TAG","Not Main Thread");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(8); // the webview is now stuck during these 8 seconds
                    return "123";
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
                }
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(task);

        try {
            return future.get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "111";
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "111";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

This code is invoked with the following javascript code:

```
var response = webCallHandler.jsToAndroidNativeFunc(request.data);
```

This is exactly what makes the UI freeze because [javascript is single-threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2734025/187808). We must make asynchronous invocations with callbacks. Just like Ajax.

#### Original answer

I don't know the js android interface. What I do know is that your function is waiting for an answer. I.e. `Future.get()` is a blocking function. Excerpt from the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()):

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

I suggest to make this `jsToAndroidNativeFunc` void and add some callback. Also, I suggest to define an executor outside of the method. E.g. at class or app level:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{

    private final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void jsToAndroidNativeFunc(String Data, Callback callback)
    // I just made up the Callback class. There must be a way to do so with webview too.
    {

        Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    // ...
                    callback.call("123"); // no return, but call the js callback
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
                }
            }
        };

        EXECUTOR.submit(task); // using the static executor
        // no Future, no return either. Js side will execute asynchronously.
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this jsToAndroidNativeFunc has to return a response and cannot be void. The javascript I injected to the webview awaits for that response :
`var response = webCallHandler.jsToAndroidNativeFunc(request.data);" `

Comment: At [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14145116/187808) they solve similar problem:Android webview + callback. On the other hand, it's this waiting js code that makes your app freeze. Bottom line: javascript is single-threaded.